# iOS 15 - Assigning unicode character text to UITextField which has isSecureTextEntry as true doesn't work as expected

Tags: swift, objective-c, unicode, uitextfield, ios15

I am working on a project which has password textfields which is just like OTP text fields, which will allow only one character in a secure text field.

In this there is a support for backspace as well.
When the textfield becomes first responder, the unicode character @"\u200B" is added as text of text field.

My problem is,
It **works fine till iOS 14**, but **not in iOS 15**, the unicode character in secure text field takes it as a character and displays text on text field.

**The issue only occurs when the text field allows secure text entry.**

Below is the code which I used in demo project to show the issue:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [txtUser setSecureTextEntry:false];
    [txt1 setSecureTextEntry:true];

    txtUser.text = @"\u200B";
    txt1.text = @"\u200B";
```

}

In above code, **the txtUser is does not allow secure text entry** but **txt1 allows secure text entry**.

Below are the screenshots of both iOS 14 and 15:

**iOS 14 result:**

Normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ZPd.png

Color blended layers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XupKH.png

**iOS 15 result:**

Normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtj46.png

Color blended layers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB33H.png

I want same result in iOS 15 that is there in iOS 14.
I searched for so many solutions, but didn't find the correct one yet!

Thanks!!